# jQuery: attr for style not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Why does the following code won't work in IE browsers (7 and 8)?

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
  if(($.trim($(this).attr("style"))) != "display: none;"){
     //if content
  }else if(($.trim($(this).attr("style"))) == "display: none;"){
     //else content
  }
});
```

Note: The first 4 li elements do not not have "style" attribute and the remaining 8 do.

Comment: Hack could we plese see the html that goes wiht this ?

Comment: you could show us in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what version of jquery are are you using ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't check the `style` attribute.  It won't necessarily return the current reality, and it doesn't take into account any styles defined elsewhere.

Use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector) filter, or use the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) method:

```
if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {

}

// or

if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {

}
```

I'd generally prefer the first syntax, as it takes a little more into account than just the `display` style.

Comment: @Pack Glad to help. If an answer has resolved your question, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
("ul li").each(function() {
  if(($.trim($(this).css("display"))) != "none"){
     //if content
  }else if(($.trim($(this).css("display"))) == "none"){
     //else content
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are comparing an attribut with a property, display is an element property, not an attribute.

Better with something like this:

```
if( ($.trim($(this).is(':visible') ) {
    // it's visible, do something
}
else { // no need for second condition, we *know* it's not visible!
    // it's not visible so do something else

}
```

Comment: If you call `$.trim` on a boolean, it will always return a truthy string. `$.trim(false)` is `"false"`.